# Mapreduce job, which takes the input from multiple files and will display the output as word—list of files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new to the hadoop, Here I'm trying to write a MR job, which takes the input from multiple files and will display the output as word—list of files but I'm not able to fetch the ile names

- Ex: hadoop  [file1, file2,file3]
      Hive    [file2, file3]

Answer (score 0):

This is quite similar to the Word Count program.

From Map emit,

```
Word,Filename
```

To extract filename,

```
String fileName = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName();
```

In Reduce,

You by default would get get the filenames per word grouped. You can iterate and do what you need.